# IOS: ASIFormDataRequest with quotation marks

Tags: ios, json, asihttprequest

I have to send json to a web service that only accepts it via a POST variable.

ASIFormDataRequest insists on escaping my quotation marks.

any help would be appreciated

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"user\":\"username\",\"pass\":\"password\"}"];
[request setPostValue:body forKey:@"body"];
[request startSynchronous];

output: "{\"user\":\"username\",\"pass\":\"password\"}"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASIFormDataRequest JSON encoding issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210565/asiformdatarequest-json-encoding-issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JosephH is right

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [request appendPostData:[dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try Converting the parameter into JSON representation before sending it through SBJSON or whatever JSON parser you are using.